# Can't find overloaded Execute method for SchemaExport

Tags: nhibernate, orm

i have a problem with my first app with NHibernate like ORM

in this example: http://nhibernate.info/doc/tutorials/first-nh-app/your-first-nhibernate-based-application.html

they use this simple test:

```
public void Can_generate_schema()
        {
            var cfg = new Configuration();
            cfg.Configure();
            cfg.AddAssembly(typeof (Product).Assembly);

            new SchemaExport(cfg).Execute(false, true, false, false);
        }
```

but i cant find Execute method for 4 parameters 3 only:

```
new SchemaExport(cfg).Execute(false, true, false);
```

what am i missing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That overload has been removed in v2.1.

Comment: i tried find it in release notes: http://nhjira.koah.net/secure/ReleaseNote.jspa?projectId=10000&styleName=Html&version=10275

but i cant, what they change exactly?

Comment: Check out http://nhibernate.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/nhibernate/trunk/nhibernate/releasenotes.txt?view=markup&pathrev=4185 and http://nhibernate.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/nhibernate/trunk/nhibernate/src/NHibernate/Tool/hbm2ddl/SchemaExport.cs?r1=4185&r2=4184&pathrev=4185 - the fourth boolean parameter (format) was removed.